# TypeToken on map and it's elements

Tags: java, gson

I've got a map of the following structure `Map<Identity, Boolean>` which is to convert to `gson new Gson().toJson(obj);` To set up rules for converting Identity objects I use this  construction `new TypeToken<Identity>(){}.getType();` and this forks fine. But when i try to apply this one `new TypeToken<Map<Identity, Boolean>>(){}.getType();` i got this {"Identity@23b5810f":true}. Is there any way to specify TypeToken for mapkey other than changing Identity's toString() method?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[Maps as JSON arrays](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.html#enableComplexMapKeySerialization()) is the way it's possible to customize how the keys should be serialized.

Comment: While this may answer the question, it is better to provide the actual information here and not just a link. [Link-only answers are not considered good answers and will probably be deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Answer (score 0):

You do have Identity as key. What you see is String presentation of this Identity instance in your output.

In you code you should use these keys as Identity objects. It should work.

Comment: Yeah, but i want to get smth like `{"id":"123","name":"..."}` out of Identity instead of `{"Identity@23b5810f":true}`

Comment: Then you have to wrap Identity to your own object with your own toString() method.
Another way, if it is JSON - compose JSON string by yourself and provide whatever you want for the key/value pair. Either way you will never have object from Map by key "123" because "123" is the String and not Identity.

Comment: Oh i got it, Identity is the name of my own class, that's kind of ambiguity. So, for instance, instead of Identity could be any other class i.e. Person and i want to retrieve fields of that class. I've tried to fiddle with toString() in my Identity class to make it match but i wonder if exists some construction like `new TypeToken<Map<...here i want to use TypeToken on Identity, Boolean>(){}.getType();`